# How to properly quit a program in python

Tags: python, string, python-3.x, quit

Im a middle school student, and im starting to learn coding in python. I have been watching video tutorials, but i cant seem to figure out how to make the game quit if you type q. here what i have..

```
print('How old do you thing Fred the Chicken is?')
number = 17

Quit = q
run = 17
while run:

guess = int(input('Enter What You Think His Age Is....'))

print('How old do you thing Fred the Chicken is?')
number = 17

Quit = 'q'
run = 17
while run:

guess = int(input('Enter What You Think His Age Is....'))

if guess == number:
    print('Yes :D That is his age...')
    run = False
elif guess < number:
    print('No, Guess a little higher...')
elif guess > number:
    print('No, Guess a little lower....')

print('Game Over')
print('Press Q to Quit')

if run == False:
choice = input('Press Q to Quit')
if choice == 'q'
import sys
exit(0)
```

Comment: if you want, you could do `number = random.randint(0,10)` so it won't always be set to 17 every game. just remember to add `import random` at the top of your file. read more [here](http://docs.python.org/library/random.html#random.randint)

Answer (score 14):

### Getting `Q` as input

```
Quit = int(input('Press Q to Quit')
```

You're asking for `Q` as the input, but only accepting an `int`. So take off the `int` part:

```
Quit = input('Press Q to Quit')
```

Now `Quit` will be whatever the user typed in, so let's check for "Q" instead of `True`:

```
if Quit == "Q":
```

Instead of `sys.exit(0)`, you can probably just end your while look with [`break`](http://docs.python.org/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-break-statement) or just `return` if you're in a function.

Also, I don't recommend the name "Quit" for a variable that just stores user input, since it will end up confusing.

And remember that indentation is important in Python, so it needs to be:

```
if run == False:
    choice = input('Press Q to Quit')
    if choice == "Q":
        # break or return or..
        import sys
        sys.exit(0)
```

That may just be a copy/paste error though.

### Indentation and Syntax

I fixed the indentation and removed some extraneous code (since you duplicate the outer loop and some of the print statements) and got this:

```
print('How old do you thing Fred the Chicken is?')
number = 17

run = True
while run:

    guess = int(input('Enter What You Think His Age Is....t'))

    if guess == number:
        print('Yes :D That is his age...')
        run = False
    elif guess < number:
        print('No, Guess a little higher...')
    elif guess > number:
        print('No, Guess a little lower....')

    if run == False:
        print('Game Over')
        choice = input('Press Q to Quit')
        if choice == 'q'
            break
```

This gave me a syntax error:

> blong@ubuntu:~$ python3 chicken.py
>     File "chicken.py", line 23
>       if choice == 'q'
>                      ^
>   SyntaxError: invalid syntax

So Python is saying there's something wrong after the `if` statement. If you look at the other `if` statements, you'll notice that this one is missing the `:` at the end, so change it to:

```
if choice == 'q':
```

So with that change the program runs, and seems to do what you want.

### Some suggestions

- Your instructions say "Press Q to Quit", but you actually only accept "q" to quit. You may want to accept both. Python has an [operator called `or`](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#boolean-operations-and-or-not), which takes two truth values (`True` or `False`) and returns `True` if either of them is `True` (it actually does more than this with values besides `True` and `False`, see the documentation if you're interested).

  Examples:

  ```
  >> True or True
  True
  >>> True or False
  True
  >>> False or True
  True
  >>> False or False
  False
  ```

  So we can ask for Q or q with `if choice == "Q" or choice == "q":`.

  Another option is to convert the string to lower case and only check for `q`, using `if choice.lower() == "q":`. If `choice` was Q, it would first convert it to q (with the `.lower()`), then do the comparison.
- Your number is always 17. Python has a function called [random.randint()](http://docs.python.org/library/random.html#random.randint) that will give you a random number, which might make the game more fun. For example, this would make the chicken's age between 5 and 20 (inclusive):

  ```
  number = random.randint(5, 20)
  ```

Comment: hmm..... I tried it like 5 different ways and it came out with an invalid syntax... there must be some spacing error... thank you for your help. Could you check my current code? ill edit my current post so you can see the fixes...

Comment: @user1766994 Your current post isn't indented correctly. You need to indent by four spaces after each `while:` or `if:` (also `class` and `def`). Please update it with correct indentation, and also include the entire error message. Remember, **in Python indentation matters**.

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to exit certain things. For loops, it is using `break`, and for functions you can use `return`. However, for programs, if you wish to exit your program before interpretation finishes (end of the script) there are two different types of `exit()` functions. There is `sys.exit()` which is part of the `sys` module, and there is `exit()` and `quit()` which is a built-in. However, `sys.exit()` is intended for programs not in IDLE (python interactive), while the built-in `exit()` and `quit()` functions are intended for use in IDLE.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [`break`](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/controlflow.html#break-and-continue-statements-and-else-clauses-on-loops) statement to break out of a `while` loop:

```
while True:
    guess = int(input("...")

    # ...rest of your game's logic...

    # Allow breaking out of the loop
    choice = input("Enter Q to quit, or press return to continue")
    if choice.lower() == "q":
        break
```

That means the interpreter exits the `while` loop, continues looking for more commands to run, but reaches the end of the file! Python will then exit automatically - there's no need to call `sys.exit`

(as an aside, you should rarely use `sys.exit`, it's really just used to set non-zero [exit-status](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exit_status), *not* for controlling how your program works, like escaping from a `while` loop)

Finally, the main problem with the code you posted is indentation - you need to put the appropriate number of spaces at the start of each line - where you have something like:

```
if run == False:
choice = input('Press Q to Quit')
```

It *must* be like this:

```
if run == False:
    choice = input('Press Q to Quit')
```

Same with anything like `while`, `for`, `if` and so on.